# ActiveRecord to_json: conditionally include associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a way to conditionally include associated models when I use .to_json on a model.

In a simplified example, assume the following two models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  attr_accessible :bar_type
end
```

I currently have:

```
f = Foo.find "3"
j = f.to_json(:include => { :bars => {:some, :attributes}}
```

and this works. What I need to find a way to do is only include bar instances that have bar_type == 'what?'

I'm hoping there's a way to conditionally pulling in the bar instances, or perhaps even use a scope to limit the bars that are included in the json output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the conditions don't change, you could do this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :what_bars, :class_name=>"Bar", 
                       :foreign_key=>:foo_id, 
                       :conditions=>"bars.bar_type = 'what'"
end

f = Foo.find "3"
j = f.to_json(:include => :what_bars)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll give this a try and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using something like json_builder https://github.com/dewski/json_builder