# JSON rendering with including by condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
@menu.to_json(include: {submenus: {include: :items}})
```

But I want to get only menus with 'is_enabled' equals true; submenus and items too. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, query database to get only menus where is_enable is true.

Comment: Give me a piece of code please.

Comment: @menu = Menu.where("is_enable = 1")

Comment: You may get some help from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317849/activerecord-to-json-conditionally-include-associations and be sure it wont affect other places.